# Keep footer on screen?

Tags: css, html, layout

I need to keep my footer at the bottom of the browser window, this is NOT bottom of the page like sticky footer.

I want it to always be on screen, but at the bottom of the browser window even if they scroll up or down.

Comment: You could have [googled this](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=html+sticky+footer) faster then it took you to ask the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`position: fixed;` is what you're looking for.

You can position your footer with `bottom: 0; left: 0;` for example.

- [Fixed positioning on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)
- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xTRpn/)

*If you are one of the unlucky few still caring about IE6, it does not support this, but there are [hacks](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/).*